# Trying to change a varchar to not display any decimal points or values after

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a append query where the original value of the Manager_ID field is a varchar(250) value = 31.0.  I need to convert or cast the value to display only '31' and remove everything after the decimal.  I have tried both Convert & Cast to both an integer or nvarchar, without success.  I keep getting the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '31.0' to data type int.

I have played with the different field types without success both in the insert table and the data table.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Error MSG for convert(int, convert(decimal(9,2),[Manager_ID]))

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblUsers]
      ( [User_ID]
       ,[FirstName]
       ,[LastName]
       ,[FullName]
       ,[EMail]
       ,[UserRoles]
       ,[PostionType]
       ,[ManagerID]
       ,[UUID]
       ,[External_UUID]
       ,[home_Location_id]
       ,[Home_Organization_ID]
       ,[Record_types]
       ,[Location_Ceiling_ID]
       ,[Organization_Ceiling_ID]
       ,[Payroll_Identifier]
       ,[Created_Date]
       ,[Created_Time]
       ,[Update_Date]
       ,[Update_Time])   
Select  id-- User_ID
        ,first_name 
        ,last_name 
        ,full_name 
        ,email 
        ,role_id --UserRoles
        ,position --PositionType
        ,**cast(Manager_id as nvarchar(10)) as ManagerID**
        ,uuid 
        ,external_uuid 
        ,home_location_id
        ,home_organization_id
        ,[type] --Record_Types
        ,location_ceiling_id 
        ,organization_ceiling_id
        ,payroll_identifier 
        ,Left(Convert(varchar(20), created_at, 120),10) as Create_Date
        ,Right(convert(varchar(16), created_at, 120),5) as Create_Time
        ,left(Convert(varchar(20), updated_at, 120),10) as Update_Date
        ,Right(convert(varchar(16), updated_at, 120),5) as Update_Time
    from [stg].[Users]
```

***Final Solution***

```
,SUBSTRING(manager_id, 1, 
  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',manager_id) - 1 < 0 
   THEN LEN(manager_id) 
   ELSE CHARINDEX('.',manager_id) - 1 END) as  ManagerID
```

Comment: You need to convert to the actual datatype before converting to an int e.g. `select convert(int, convert(decimal(9,2),'31.0'))`

Comment: how do I include the field name not the value?

Comment: Replace the value with the column name? Like you say you have already tried?

Comment: please above for error msg.

Comment: In that case you have bad data and need to decide how you want to handle it.

Comment: Does a null value come into play for the bad data?

Comment: No... null can be converted to any datatype, you must have a string that isn't a normal numeric value. One might ask at this point why you are storing numbers as strings in the first place.

Comment: The original data is in string format from an API call and I am trying to convert it to a number without decimals.  any suggestions?

Comment: Check the data... some of it is wrong. We can't help without a [mre] including actual data which reproduces the issue. And note the 'minimal' i.e. the simplest query which shows the issue, we don't need your entire query.

Comment: Use `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST` if you want to null out incorrect values

Answer (score 1):

Convert function is very helpful for this. Below is what I would use:

```
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblUsers]
      ( [User_ID]
       ,[FirstName]
       ,[LastName]
       ,[FullName]
       ,[EMail]
       ,[UserRoles]
       ,[PostionType]
       ,[ManagerID]
       ,[UUID]
       ,[External_UUID]
       ,[home_Location_id]
       ,[Home_Organization_ID]
       ,[Record_types]
       ,[Location_Ceiling_ID]
       ,[Organization_Ceiling_ID]
       ,[Payroll_Identifier]
       ,[Created_Date]
       ,[Created_Time]
       ,[Update_Date]
       ,[Update_Time])   
Select  id as User_ID
        ,first_name 
        ,last_name 
        ,full_name 
        ,email 
        ,role_id as UserRoles
        ,position as PositionType
        ,convert(int, convert(decimal(9,2),[Manager_ID])) as ManagerID
        ,uuid 
        ,external_uuid 
        ,home_location_id
        ,home_organization_id
        ,[type] as Record_Types
        ,location_ceiling_id 
        ,organization_ceiling_id
        ,payroll_identifier 
        ,Left(Convert(varchar(20), created_at, 120),10) as Create_Date
        ,Right(convert(varchar(16), created_at, 120),5) as Create_Time
        ,left(Convert(varchar(20), updated_at, 120),10) as Update_Date
        ,Right(convert(varchar(16), updated_at, 120),5) as Update_Time
    from [stg].[Users]
```

Comment: Thank you, however, I have tried this without success see error message. "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

Comment: To confirm, are all recording in the ManagerID column true numeric values? I get this error when there's other string based values in the field when trying to convert.

Comment: The original data is a varchar(250) and I want to convert change the value to a number and remove the decimal due to the issue this will become a foreign key, in other tables.  I am check the data for any  erroneous data.

Comment: Considering the source data is varchar, virtually any value could exist.   Best to use try_convert().   Rather than throwing an error, it will return a NULL value which would be easy to trap.

Comment: See bottom of my question for final Results